# Java Regex: Why matcher.group() does not work without matcher.find()?

Tags: java, regex

Following code gives exception on first run. But when I set break point on matcher line and evaluate a few commands in Netbeans Watcher. It works. Why??

```
String regex = "/I-TASSER/output/(?<jobId>.*?)>";
Pattern pattern;
Matcher matcher;
if (Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(document.html()).find()) {
    pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    matcher = pattern.matcher(document.html());
    jobId = matcher.group("jobId"); //always give exception, so breakpoint here
}
```

I put following four lines in netbeans variable watcher

```
matcher.group("jobId"); //exception
matcher.find();         //true
matcher.group("jobId"); //S12345 /*found*/
```

Why it is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are re-assigning the `Pattern` and `Matcher` references within your `if` statement.

As such, you need to invoke `matcher.find()` again within that context to be able to invoke `matcher.group()`, otherwise it will throw an `IllegalStateException` - see [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28%29).

A much clearer and simpler syntax would be:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(document.html());
if (matcher.find()) {
    jobId = matcher.group("jobId");
}
```

Final advice, regex is not suitable for parsing html.

See the gazillion other posts about it.

Comment: Do I have to run find() number of times equal to the number of groups?

Comment: @LifeH2O not at all. You have to invoke `find()` (or `matches()`) prior to be able to invoke `group()`. The number of groups is defined by the `Pattern` itself.

Answer (score 5):

The work for establishing groups happens in `matches` or `find`.

```
if (matcher.matches()) {
    ... matcher.group(...)
}

while (matcher.find()) {
    ... matcher.group(...)
}
```

With find there even is an iteration involved. And `matches` considers the entire text whereas `find` any subtext.
As it even is not clear what to do (matches or find) it does not even make sense to look what is found.

Twice compiling pattern and calling its matcher was probably an experiment, and can be cleaned up.

Answer (score 1):

```
String regex = "/I-TASSER/output/(?<jobId>.*?)>";
String expression = document.html();
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(expression);
while (matcher.find()) {
    String group = matcher.group();
}
```